# Formal, mathematically-minded introduction to generative grammar?

Tags: reference-request, generative-grammar

I'm looking for a formal, mathematically-minded introduction to contemporary generative grammar theory, where all the concepts, such as dominance, c-command, government, etc. are defined formally in mathematical terms.

An example for the kind of text I'm interested in is [this](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/Kracht/courses/compling2-2007/formal.pdf) set of notes.

This set of notes is great; however, I am looking for other texts, ideally at least two more, so that if one of them has an error or inconsistency, I can consult the others for a clarification.

For example, the concept of *dominance* as defined in the above set of notes (on p. 45) is irreflexive, i.e. a node doesn't dominate itself, but then later, in defining *c-command* (immediately following definition 6.50 on p. 521), it makes a distinction between *proper* and unqualified dominance. This is an inconsistency.

This was just one example; there are others, hence the quest for other texts.

It is crucial that the approach be mathematically-oriented, since it has been my experience with non-mathematical textbooks on generative grammar that they are simply not sufficiently precise.

For instance, when defining the concept of *dominance* most don't even address the question of whether they consider this relation to be reflexive or not, and the [one reference](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/box-nodes.html) that I found – let's call it UPENN – that did address this question, defines it as reflexive, in contradiction to the way this term is used elsewhere. Consequently, UPENN's definition of such concepts as *c-command* is different to those found elsewhere, for instance it is implied by UPENN's definition that a node doesn't c-command itself.

Comment: The notion that mathematical stringency is a good way to teach syntax and grammar is debatable. My experience has been that the formalist who defines things precisely in mathematical terms makes the study of syntax and grammar inaccessible to the vast majority of students. Formalism are best used sparingly, and when they are used, they should be surrounded by normal language descriptions and numerous examples for illustration.

Comment: @TimOsborne: You seem to imply that a text that takes a formal approach is intrinsically one that lacks examples and informal motivation and discussion. This attitude has no basis. I would say the opposite. While a text that takes a formal approach can succeed or fail in the area of pedagogy, one that avoids formality is inherently pedagogically lacking. At any rate, what you think about formalism is irrelevant for the purposes of this question, which isn't meant  to elicit a discussion about the merits of formalism in linguistics, but simply to ask for pointers to the literature.

Comment: My comment is questioning the validity of the approach to teaching syntax and grammar suggested in your question, and it is pointing to a very interesting and related question about how valuable formalisms are in linguistics. Note as well that this is the comment section, not the answer section. Concerning the actual content of your question, I own many of the textbooks on syntax and grammar that have come out in the past four decades. The ones that profess to do formal syntax are the ones that I reach to least often. They are not accessible.

Comment: have you looked at Collins & Stabler's paper 'A formalization of minimalist syntax'? it's not a textbook and certainly isn't meant as an introduction, but i found it useful in getting a deeper understanding on concepts usually discussed only informally.

Comment: @one-off-post: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: I think you're seeing a distinction between "proper" domination and some other kind of domination that just isn't there. Kracht isn't being inconsistent. Now I don't know what kind of precision you're ultimately after or whether you'll be able to find it, but have you read the primary sources, like Chomsky's [*The Minimalist Program*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/minimalist-program-20th-anniversary-edition)? It may not be mathematical enough, but it sure is thorough and I'd think precise in its definitions.

Comment: I take it back, in def 6.52 he says "dominates (not necessarily properly)". As far as I can tell, that's not a distinction he does explain (and I'd have no idea what he means, though it's been many years since I've thought about GG at this level of detail), so yes, poor work there.

Comment: @curiousdannii: That's right. And in def 6.50, which is where he defines c-command (as I pointed out in my post) he writes: "the smallest branching node that properly dominates x dominates y". I'm glad we came to agree on this point. Sorry for my rudeness earlier, but honestly, it really is a clear-cut case. Thanks again for your reference, I'll check it out.

Comment: If it was only in 6.50, then I'd still probably think that "properly" doesn't carry any significant meaning, that it's just an adjective like "formal" that you might add before something to remind readers that you're referring to the formal definition you introduced hundreds of pages before, and not some other sense from other writings. Even now that I know "proper" has some meaning to him, I wouldn't say 6.50 is inconsistent as I'd assume the unqualified "dominate" is the same as "properly dominate" as that's what all other definitions of c-command have. Sloppy work, but not an inconsistency.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Let's agree to (properly) disagree on this point.

Comment: I wish I knew the topic, and suggest that *inconsistency* of a terminus is expected, if it is defined to be not dominating itself (but this requires the defenition itself [or its application] to be a dominant node in the text). Otherwise, did you try contact the author?

Comment: @vectory: As I wrote in my post, this was just one example to illustrate my motivation for seeking further texts. My question is not about this issue. It is about seeking pointers to the literature.

Comment: Partee’s Mathematical methods in linguistics is a good book (and a linguist’s must-read anyway). It’s focus is on pure maths but the chapters on linguistic issues are nicely formalised.

Comment: @Atamiri: I'll check it out, but it seems unlikely that a book published in 1990, before Chomsky's Minimalist Program, would be able to adequately describe comtemporary generative grammar theory, a criterion stated in my post.

Comment: Yes, it’s old but at least some of the concepts are defined there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no work that is simultaneously mathematically explicit in the sense that you desire and sufficiently representative of the concepts of current Minimalism. The reason is that the underlying linguistic concepts are themselves not clearly enough resolved that mathematical modeling would be appropriate.

Comment: @user6726: Nonesense. The link I gave in my original post is a good example for the kind of text I am looking for (and I stated this very clearly in the post). Additionally, the  Collins & Stabler's paper recommended by one-off-post fits the bill.

Comment: @EvanAad:  Balderdash. If you think Collins & Stabler or Kracht constitute the kind of work on formal specification of Minimalism that you're asking for, then you're wasting our time because you've answered your own question.